# Receive a string, convert to calculate and display response, but.. Can't split

Tags: python, python-2.7

My homework question:

> Create a script to receive the birth date and return the user's age

I tried this:

```
ano_atual = 2012                                       
data_nascimento = input('Digite sua data de nascimento (dd/mm/aaaa): ')
dia, mes, ano = map(int, data_nascimento.split('/'))
idade = ano_atual - ano
print idade
```

But I am stuck with this error:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: As a side note, `idade = ano_atual - ano` doesn't look correct to me. Someone born on 31.12.72 is 39 years old, not 40.

Comment: Yeah, never thought of that .. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Since this is a homework, no ;) I think you can figure that out yourself. Very simple stuff, actually.

Comment: Another side note, Python has a useful module called [datetime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html). And it can do the above easily. Besides, your code is not 'dynamic' (if that's the right word), so it can't be used, say, next year. Here is another solution:

`>>from datetime import date`

`>>data_nascimento = raw_input('Digite sua data de nascimento (dd/mm/aaaa): ')`

`>>dia, mes, ano = map(int, data_nascimento.split('/'))`

`>>d1 = date(ano, mes, dia)`

`>>difference = date.today() - d1`

`>>print difference.days/365 #This will get rid of all remainders as you would expect.`

Comment: Haha thg435, I'll think what you said ;D / Abdulhaq Elhouderi, I'll study this form.

Answer (score 6):

You probably want [raw_input](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#raw_input) instead of [input](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#input).  `input` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input())` in python2.x.  So your string is being cast to an integer.  just like:

```
a=30/6/2012
```

would be.  (In this case, `a` is the result of 30 divided by 6 divided by 2012 which is 0 because of integer division in python 2.)

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- Working on it.

Comment: Just WOW!, asked 2 mins ago, 3 answers within 2 minutes, how am I going to get any chance with this speed :D

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- Yeah.  I wanted to add the explanation about why a date which doesn't look like an integer would end up being an integer after `input` does it's thing. -- that was higher priority than the links which can easily be googled.

Comment: Even if I convert to integer before it is recommended to use raw_input?

Comment: Yes, use `raw_input`. You can enter and execute any valid Python code with `input` and that is a big security risk. In Python 3.x `input` behaves like `raw_input` in Python 2.x.

Comment: @crf_h0m3r you don't want to convert to an integer before splitting.  Splitting only works on strings which is what `raw_input` returns.  As a side note, `input` is generally not recommended because it is a large security problem (users can run untrusted code).  Note that your original code will work if you pass a string -- e.g. "30/6/2012" instead of 30/6/2010, but again, you really do want `raw_input` here.

Answer (score 0):

use `raw_input()`, `input()` doesn't work here

Check out the tutorial on YouTube: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qsTdaxahTsM