# python input() not working as expected

Tags: python

I am a python newbie.I am getting familiar with loops and tried this example from a book

```
while True:
        s = input('Enter something : ')
        if s == 'quit':
                break
        print('Length of the string is', len(s))
print('Done')
```

However the output is as follows

```
Enter something : ljsdf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trial_2.py", line 2, in <module>
    s = input('Enter something : ')
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'ljsdf' is not defined
```

Comment: for what it's worth:  This is essentially a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/11295325/748858 although you probably wouldn't be able to find it if you didn't know where to look ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to use `raw_input()` instead (Python 2.x), because [`input()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) is equivalent to `eval(raw_input())`, so it parses and evaluates your input as a valid Python expression.

```
while True:
        s = raw_input('Enter something : ')
        if s == 'quit':
                break
        print('Length of the string is', len(s))
print('Done')
```

**Note:**

`input()` doesn't catch user errors (e.g. if user inputs some invalid Python expression). `raw_input()` can do this, because it converts the input to a `string`. [For futher information, read Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input).

Comment: I think your note is a little backwards. `raw_input()` doesn't convert the input *to* a string so much as *not* try to evaluate said string into code.

Comment: I just quoted [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html)

Comment: raw_input() is not working in Kamodo Editor..and also input() is not working.. I got below this error > NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined

Answer (score 4):

you want `raw_input()` in python2

```
while True:
    s = raw_input('Enter something : ')
    if s == 'quit':
            break
    print 'Length of the string is', len(s)
print 'Done'
```

`input()` tries to evaluate (dangerously!) what you give it

Answer (score 3):

Your code will work fine in python 3.x

But if you are using python 2 you will have to input string using raw_input()

> ```
> while True:
>     s = raw_input('Enter something : ')
>     if s == 'quit':
>         break
>     print('Length of the string is', len(s))
> print('Done')
> ```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're using Python 2.x, while the code is expected to be run in Python 3.x.

[`input` in Python 2.x](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) evaluates the input string unlike [`input` in Python 3.x](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input).

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2.x `input()` is designed to return numbers, int or float depending on the input from the user, you can also enter variable names.

you need to use:

```
raw_input('Enter something: ')
```

The error is caused because Python thinks that "ljsdf" is the name of a variable, and that's why it raises this exception:

`NameError: name 'ljsdf' is not defined`

becuase "ljsdf" is not defined as a variable. :D

`raw_input()` is safer to use, and then convert the input to whatever other type after :D