# python input() not working! (raspberry pi camera program)

Tags: python

I am on my raspberry pi making a camera program (code)

```
import picamera
import sys
import time

question=input('do you want to take a picture(pic) take a timed picture(time) or a video(vid)')
if question=='pic':
    time=0
elif question=='time':
    time=1
elif question=='vid':
    print ('coming soon')
    sys.exit()
num=0
camera = picamera.PiCamera()
camera.start_preview()
input('press any key to take picture')
if time==1 :
    print ('5')
    time.sleep(1)
    print ('4')
    time.sleep(1)
    print ('3')
    time.sleep(1)
    print ('2')
    time.sleep(1)
    print ('1')
    time.sleep(1)
    print ('0')
camera.capture(num)
num=num + 1
```

and when I ran it, it asked

> Do you want to take a picture(pic) take a timed picture(time) or a video(vid)

just as it was suppose to I replied

> pic

then it gave me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/pi/Desktop/camera.py", line 5, in <module>
   question=input('do you want to take a picture(pic) take a timed picture(time) or a video(vid)')
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'pic' is not defined
```

What happened?

Comment: Use `raw_input` instead of `input`.

Comment: thanks it worked now i just have to enable my picamera :)

Comment: @Cyber, please post that comment as an answer. Doing so will be helpful to people browsing the Unanswered Questions tab for questions that really haven't been answered yet..

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21250351/1982962)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Cyber said in the comments, use python's raw_input() function vis-a-vis input.

raw_input() will take anything from STDIN as a STR type until the user hits enter.

```
question = raw_input("Do you want to take a picture(pic) take a timed picture(time) or a video(vid)?")
```