# Unable to get desired result from " if " in python

Tags: python

I have an assignment to simply print dates in calendar like format. Everything is done except when the user enter some alphabet(string) in input, console gives an error statement standing the fact that i have included the code in `if` statement.

This is the error i am getting in console:

```
Please enter the number/name of the month (in any case/form)
you want the program to display calendar of:    jan
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-16-8ac5bd6555cd>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('D:/Studies & Learnings/Programming/Python/Calendar.py', wdir='D:/Studies & Learnings/Programming/Python')

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 685, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 71, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "D:/Studies & Learnings/Programming/Python/Calendar.py", line 3, in <module>
    month = input("\nPlease enter the number/name of the month (in any case/form)\nyou want the program to display calendar of:\t")

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\kernel\zmq\ipkernel.py", line 364, in <lambda>
    input = lambda prompt='': eval(raw_input(prompt))

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

NameError: name 'jan' is not defined
```

I have just started learning python. And this is my very first code in python. So if I am doing something obviously wrong, kindly let me know instead of rating my question 'negative value'

Thank you all...

```
month = input("\nPlease enter the number/name of the month (in any case/form)\nyou want the program to display calendar of:\t")

month = str(month)

if(month == "1" or month == "jan" or month == "Jan" or month == "january" or month == "January"):

    monthNumber = 1
    monthName = "January"

elif(month == "2" or month == "feb" or month == "Feb" or month == "february" or month == "Februrary"):

    monthNumber = 2    
    monthName = "February"
```

Comment: Use `raw_input` instead of `input`. `month = str(month)` line is not required as `month` is already a string.

Comment: You've misidentified the problem, which makes it hard to ask the right question. Read the console output from the bottom. The first line gives you the error: `NameError: name 'jan' is not defined`. The remaining lines show where this error occurred. The first two lines are higher level than your code. The third is the line you care about: `month = input(...`. So your question is actually "Python 2 input causes name is not defined error". Stick that in search to go directly to your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21250504/3697870

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 2, the `input()` function, for reasons that must have made sense at the time, [tries to evaluate what's typed as a Python expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input). Thus, when you type `jan` into an `input()` prompt, it tries to find the variable `jan`. This is not what you want in this (or pretty much any other*) case; you should use `raw_input()` instead.

Note that in Python 3, which will be the only supported version starting in 2020, the `input()` function of Python 2 is removed, and the `raw_input()` function is renamed to just `input()`.

---

* It might seem that when you want a number, `input()` makes sense; when the user types `2` to an `input()` prompt, you get an `int`, not a `str`. But there are massive security problems any time you run `eval`, which `input()` does, so you should still use `int(raw_input())` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You need not use month=string(month) as the input is in string form only. Remove the line and code should work

Comment: Are you sure? This is in Python 2. Did you run and check?