# Neither branch of if-else executes

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement, pycharm

I am a beginner in Python and trying to write a program to find whether a letter is vowel or consonant using a list and for loop. I have two conditions which both print something, but neither one executes and my output is empty. Why?

The code is as follows:

```
    al=input("Enter the alphabet")

    list=['a','e','i','o','u']


    for p in list:
      if al==p:
          print("The alphabet is a vowel")


    else:
      print("The alphabet is a consonant")
```

The output is:

C:\Users\dell\PycharmProjects\HelloWorld\venv\Scripts\python.exe

C:/Users/dell/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld/app.py

Enter the alphabete

Process finished with exit code 0

Could someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `else` isn’t working the way you think it will. It only executes if there’s no `break` to exit the loop. (Note that it’s attached to the `for` loop, not the `if` statement.)

Try this.

```
al=input("Enter the alphabet")

list_=['a','e','i','o','u']


for p in list_:
  if al==p:
      print("The alphabet is a vowel")
      break  # exit the loop

else:  # triggers if we haven’t seen a vowel and exited.
  print("The alphabet is a consonant")
```

Incidentally, you shouldn’t name variables `list` in Python. You’ll shadow the builtin name, which can cause unexpected problems further down in the code. Seems I called the kettle black here; thanks @NanduRaj.

Comment: There is no newline included in the string returned by `input`.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy, 

You really shouldn’t name variables list in Python

Answer (score 1):

There are three issues with this code:

- on some platforms (python 2) you should use `raw_input` instead of `input`: [python input() not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250351/python-input-not-working-as-expected)
- list matching can be done like this instead : `if al in <ref_list>`
- as mentioned by @AryaMcCarthy the `else` in a `for` loop only executes when no `break` has been hit

So you can try for a python2+3 compliant code

```
import sys
if sys.version_info < (3,):
    input = raw_input

al = input("Enter the alphabet")
ref_list = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']

if al in ref_list:
    print("The alphabet is a vowel")
else:
    print("The alphabet is a consonant")
```

NOTE as noted by @ThierryLathuille, using the `past.builtins` package is maybe overkill so I replaced its usage in the example code above with a sys version info check.

Now if you have a problem getting `raw_input` or `input` be interactive, this is maybe because your terminal does not allow it ?

Comment: Writing code for a no longer supported version of Python using non-standard modules seems like a rather bad idea...

Comment: @ThierryLathuille As you can see in the original post there is no mention of python version. I went across many posts out there where users rely on python 2 still today. Now the module *is* standard for what's worth, it is part of the stdlib. Thanks !

Comment: It's not in the standard library, is described as [experimental] on its PyPI page, hasn't seen any update for months on GitHub and since 2016-10-27 on its homepage...

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
al=input("Enter the alphabet")
vowels=['a','e','i','o','u']
if al in vowels:
  print("The alphabet is a vowel")
else:
  print("The alphabet is a consonant")
```

No need for loop for this, even if this works as expected for you. It prints 5 lines like for eg if the entered character is 'e' as in your given example:

The alphabet is a consonant

The alphabet is a vowel

The alphabet is a consonant

The alphabet is a consonant

The alphabet is a consonant

Comment: You really shouldn’t name variables `list` in Python.

Comment: I copied it from the question. In your answer also, I see the variable named list. @AryaMcCarthy